# Trigger event on dialog box open

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

My dialog box is defined under the div

```
#dialogbox
```

When the dialog box opens i want to trigger an event such that it alerts open. The code im using is:

```
$("#dialogbox").dialog({open: function(){
           alert("OPEN");
          }
});
```

But this doesnt seem to trigger when dialog box is opened 
Please help

Comment: Should open, whats your console say?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can use this :

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({
  open: function( event, ui ) {}
});
```

or the event listener .on

```
$( ".selector" ).on( "dialogopen", function( event, ui ) {} );
```

More information in this page :

http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-open

Comment: Thank you . You are my new god. And considering im hindu, that doesnt count for much . But thanks a lot. I have been rattling my brain for 3 hours because of this "listener" issue.

Comment: that place (open:) is also a good spot to define handlers, since they will ony be defined once; handlers such as .on("change", function ( ... )); In fact, handlers may not work, even using .on, if placed outside of this "open:" section.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

<kbd>[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/7uYEU/)</kbd>

**HTML:**

```
<div id="dialogbox"></div>
<input id="mybutt" type="button" value="Click Me">
```

**Javascript/jQuery:**

```
$("#dialogbox").dialog({
    autoOpen:false,
    modal:true,
    title: "Use of Open event",
    width:300,
    open: function( event, ui ) {
        alert('hello');
    }
});

$('#mybutt').click(function() {
    $('#dialogbox').html('<h2>Watch this</h2>An alert box should have opened');
    $('#dialogbox').dialog('open');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It will display alert after clicking on the OK button.

```
$( "#WaitingDialog").html("Message you want to display").dialog({
   modal: true,
   buttons: { 
    Ok: function() {
       alert("hello");
    }
}});
```

It will display alert after opening the modal

```
$( "#WaitingDialog").html("Message you want to display").dialog({
    modal: true,
    buttons: { 
        open: function( event, ui ) {
              alert('hello');
          }
    }});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the **focus** event
[Click here for documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-focus)